# Mixing an exponential can never result in increasing hazard rate.

Tags: probability, poisson-process, exponential-distribution

The exponential distribution is known to have a constant hazard rate, $\lambda = \frac{f(t)}{S(t)} = \frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda t}}{e^{-\lambda t}}$ where $f(t)$ and $S(t)$ are its PDF and survival functions respectively. If we assume the $\lambda$ itself comes from a Gamma distribution and integrate over it, the resulting exponential mixture becomes a Pareto distribution, which is much heavier tailed and has decreasing hazard rate. This and other mixtures are discussed in [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1de2/04f1178ec0732a3b313305c55f59d121a644.pdf). All of those mixtures result in distributions with decreasing hazard rates.

Here is an example of such a mixture: let's say the $\lambda$ of the exponential comes from a Gamma distribution with PDF: $g(\lambda) = \theta e^{-\theta \lambda}\frac{(\theta \lambda)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}$.

The PDF of the resulting exponential-mixture distribution becomes:

$$f_T(t) = \int\limits_0^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda t} g(\lambda) d\lambda$$

If you work out the integral, this becomes:

$$f_T(t) = \frac{m\theta^m}{(t+\theta)^{m+1}}$$

This is a Pareto distribution and has a decreasing hazard rate.

*Conjecture-1*: I conjecture that mixing the exponential distribution in this way can't possibly lead to a distribution with increasing hazard rate.

The reason I suspect this is because :

*Conjecture-2*: Decreasing hazard rate distributions lead to over-dispersed point processes (variance of number of events in any interval of time is greater than the mean). While a time to event distribution with increasing hazard rate will result in an under-dispersed distribution (variance of number of events less than mean). I don't have a proof for this, but have verified it extensively with simulations.

If you believe conjecture-2, then conjecture-1 is equivalent to saying that mixing the exponential distribution can't possibly convert it into an under-dispersed process since you are adding a factor that can only increase the uncertainty.

I'm looking for either a proof or counter-example to conjecture-1, but don't know where to start.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what kind of "mixture" you are referring to. Can you give an explicit example?

Comment: @Math1000 see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $T\mid \Lambda=\lambda \sim \rm{Exp}(\lambda)$, and the pdf of $\Lambda$ is $g$, we have
$$ f_T(t) = \int_0^{+\infty} \lambda e^{-\lambda t}g(\lambda)d\lambda $$

$$ S_T(t) = \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-\lambda t}g(\lambda)d\lambda $$

$$ f_T'(t) = -\int_0^{+\infty} \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda t}g(\lambda)d\lambda $$

$$ S_T'(t) = -f(t)= -\int_0^{+\infty} \lambda e^{-\lambda t}g(\lambda)d\lambda  $$

The derivative of the harzard rate is
$$ h_T'(t) = \frac {S_T(t)f_T'(t) - f_T(t)S_T'(t)} {S_T(t)^2} 
= \frac {S_T(t)f_T'(t) + f_T(t)^2} {S_T(t)^2}$$

Since we are only concern about the sign of $h'(t)$, and its denominator is always positive, we just consider the numerator:

$$ S_T(t)f_T'(t) + f_T(t)^2 
= -\left[\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-\lambda t}g(\lambda)d\lambda\right]
\left[\int_0^{+\infty} \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda t}g(\lambda)d\lambda\right]
 + \left[\int_0^{+\infty} \lambda e^{-\lambda t}g(\lambda)d\lambda\right]^2 $$

By Hölder's inequality,
$$\begin{align} 
&\int_0^{+\infty} \left| \left[\lambda \sqrt{e^{-\lambda t}g(\lambda)}\right] \left[\sqrt{e^{-\lambda t}g(\lambda)}\right] \right| d\lambda\\
\leq & 
\left\{\int_0^{+\infty}  \left[\lambda \sqrt{e^{-\lambda t}g(\lambda)}\right]^2 d\lambda \right\}^{\frac {1} {2}}
\left\{\int_0^{+\infty}  \left[\sqrt{e^{-\lambda t}g(\lambda)}\right]^2 d\lambda \right\}^{\frac {1} {2}}
\end{align} 
$$
which implies $h'(t) \leq 0 $ for any positive $t$, i.e. The hazard rate is monotonic decreasing. You may further argue that the inequality is strict.

Comment: This actually proves a stronger statement than my conjecture. Not only can the hazard rate not be increasing, it'll always be decreasing.